# How can I set the connect timeout and soTimeout for the SolrClient used by SolrHealthIndicator in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-boot, solr

I get timeouts in my system, however it takes really long before the health check retries. I have the following exception:

```
2017-03-23 14:35:32.917 DEBUG 25941 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.h.i.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient   : Connection timed out

java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160) ~[httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84) ~[httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260) ~[httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283) ~[httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271) ~[httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123) ~[httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682) [httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486) [httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863) [httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) [httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106) [httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57) [httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:452) [solr-solrj-4.9.0.jar:4.9.0 1604085 - rmuir - 2014-06-20 06:34:04]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210) [solr-solrj-4.9.0.jar:4.9.0 1604085 - rmuir - 2014-06-20 06:34:04]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206) [solr-solrj-4.9.0.jar:4.9.0 1604085 - rmuir - 2014-06-20 06:34:04]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.SolrPing.process(SolrPing.java:70) [solr-solrj-4.9.0.jar:4.9.0 1604085 - rmuir - 2014-06-20 06:34:04]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.ping(SolrServer.java:293) [solr-solrj-4.9.0.jar:4.9.0 1604085 - rmuir - 2014-06-20 06:34:04]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.SolrHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(SolrHealthIndicator.java:37) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:38) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:81) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.getHealth(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:162) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:136) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor207.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:281) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
```

I would like to set the connect timeout and the soTimeout for the HttpClient. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you're using SolrJ - SolrJ actually has method calls to do exactly what you're looking for: [setConnectionTimeout(int)](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.html#setConnectionTimeout(int)) and [setSoTimeout(int)](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.html#setSoTimeout(int)).

`HttpSolrServer` inherits from `HttpSolrClient` so you should be all set.

Hopefully I could be of assistance (I'm new here ;D ).

Comment: I know that. However I have no idea how to make spring's healthcheck to give in a specific timeout using the methods above.